# How to solve this error in "react-native init newProj"?

Tags: react-native

I just created a sample project by using this command.

> react-native init newProj

Then I got this error.
In addition, none of my past projects are all working. What is this issue? How to solve it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use,

```
npx react-native init newProj
```